# NHibernate queryover join tables

Tags: nhibernate, join, queryover

I have a question..
How to join two tables tah are related but not have direct relation constraint in nhibernate queryover?

Table1
{
ID
Title
}

Table2
{
ID
VALUE
ALIAS
}
Table1 and Table2 has not fk relationship constraint.
Need to Do something like this:

```
Select Table1.Title, 
Table2.Alais 
from Table1
   inner join (Select Value from table2 where ALIAS = 'someAlias')
where Table1.ID = Table2.Value
```

Please help
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just using the where clause?

```
Select Table1.Title, Table2.Alais 
from Table1, Table2
where Table1.ID = Table2.Value
```

Comment: But how to do this type of query in nhibernate queryover? How to specify two From's? From Table1, Table2?

Comment: Exactly the same - HQL allows this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from

Comment: For QueryOver, you'll have to use a subquery - http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-subqueries

Comment: The NHibernate link for HQL is http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-from